# What is device -hosts in mount listing?

Tags: mount

I issued the `mount` command on a machine, and several lines begin with `-hosts`, and I can't find out what this means.

> -hosts on /net/engineering/disk1 type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=13,pgrp=1734,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,offset)

Comment: autofs is the key word here; look up automounting

Answer (score 3):

`autofs` is an [automounter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter) system available on many Unix variants including Solaris, Linux and OS X (with different code bases but similar interfaces). The software consists of a kernel component that implements a filesystem type called `autofs` and a daemon called [`automount`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/automount.8.html). The principle of an automounter is to mount a filesystem automatically when a program accesses it, and typically unmount it a few minutes after the last program stops accessing it.

The autofs software is controlled by *maps* that explain
A typical autofs configuration is for mounting network filesystems, under a hierarchy of the form `/net/$HOST_NAME/$VOLUME_NAME`. This hierarchy is available under the [built-in map name `-hosts`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/auto.master.5.html#BUILTIN_MAP_-hosts). The map name is what appears in lieu of a device name in the output of `mount`.

The entry you show indicates that autofs has enumerated the volumes exported by `engineering`, and that `disk1` is one of these volumes and is currently unmounted. If `disk1` is mounted, the filesystem type there would be something like `nfs`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be a network mount which uses the fake mount source -host. 
A

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

can verify this.